# How to scrape data using Nokogiri from elements having two 'data-' attributes

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I want to scrape data using Nokogiri from some HTML:

```
<td data-bar="hoge" data-date="2000-01-01" class="modals"></td>
<td data-bar="fuga" data-date="2000-01-02" class="modals"></td>
```

I wrote:

```
element = page.css("td[data-bar='hoge'][data-date='2000-01-01']")
```

but `element.length` returns `0`.

How do I distinguish elements having two `data-` attributes?

Comment: Your HTML sample is probably too reduced. Are the `td` you're after the only elements with `class="modals"`? If so your selector becomes `'.modals'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using XPath selectors instead. This worked for me:

```
element = page.xpath "//td[@data-bar='hoge'][@data-date='2000-01-01']"
```

In this example, the `//` portion will match any `td` element (with those attributes) in the document, which may not be desirable. In that case, you would need to write a more explicit XPath to the node.

Here's the documentation for XPath: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/